# Editing answers that say "at the time of this post"

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, hyperlinks, external-links

I just dealt with [a suggested edit to one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8525582).  It was clearly wrong.

For reference, the post was originally

> http://www.google.com/#q=win64+gcc
>
> No matter how often the download page moves around, that should find it for you.
>
> At the time of this post, the top result (and correct download site) was http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

and the edit replaced the final URL only, changing the claim to "At the time of this post, the top result (and correct download site) was http://mingw-w64.org".  That simply isn't true, that was not the top Google hit at the time I posted, nor is it the top hit now.

Nevertheless, I started doing some research to see whether the alternate URL should be incorporated in some way.  During that time, two edit reviewers chose to accept the change, even though it CLEARLY introduced incorrect information.

My final analysis shows that the downloads on SourceForge are newer than the suggested new link, so I rejected the edit entirely, instead of improving it.  In light of the statement below by the project's webmaster, I have updated my answer.

The subsequent action I *did* take was to vote to close the question -- it's a request for an offsite resource which is now offtopic.

But what could possibly have made reviewers think that modernizing a historical claim could possibly be correct?

---

Here's [a related suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8525609) -- The question says where the compiler was, historically, downloaded from, not where to get it today.  The edit is clearly incorrect.

And [another](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8525638).  Answerer is stating what he found at the time, not where the current link is.

<strike>In fact, please help reject all identical [edit suggestions by that user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2478571/poqdavid?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) (check whether they're changing the URL, valid reject reasons are "conflicts with author's intent" if it changes a historical claim, and "custom reason: Sourceforge downloads are newer than the offered link." otherwise)</strike>

Update: Those edit suggestions should all be out of the queue now.  Also, [see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297549/103167) the new URL is the correct new home, although quite a bit of consideration needs to go into future edits (and possibly also edits recently accepted) in order to provide the new location as the current web address, without changing factual descriptions of steps performed in the past.

Comment: Further note, the linked SourceForge page has a link the the other site, and the mingw-w64.org downloads do have a link to SourceForge where the new downloads are... but the mingw-w64.org page seems unmaintained, it says gcc 4.8 and 4.9 when the currently available installers are 5.x

Comment: Stack overflow's Q&As often get edited, so the date implied by "*at the time of this post*" is not always obvious. Hence I would suggest that such words always be accompanied by the actual date of the post.

Comment: "But what could possibly have made reviewers think that modernizing a historical claim could possible be correct?" Because of robo reviewers. Someone could have replaced your entire post with their favourite cookie recipe and it could as well have gotten approved.

Comment: The person that did the edit went on a link edit rampage on those links.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: Yes, and appears to have done so with the help of a search engine, **without actually reading the questions and answers before editing**

Comment: To make life even more interesting, the top Google search result **for you** won't necessarily be the top result for anyone else.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not according to what I've read and experienced. If you have a Google account, and often even if you do not, Google will remember prior searches and activity, including Google Plus usage, and modify the sort accordingly.

Comment: Incognito tab should allow seeing minimally personalized results?

Comment: @BenVoigt some people [allege](https://www.lcn.com/blog/get-different-results-google-vs-location-users/) that your country can make an enormous difference, even for countries with the same language, to the point that the top result in the UK can be "nowhere to be seen" when doing the same search in the US. Whether this is completely true, somewhat exaggerated, or total nonsense, I don't know.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Google goes very far with its profiling. For instance, if it does not know the "language" for a range of IP, it analyzes the websites that have been visited from these IPs and decides on a language to use by default throughout its services. There is really no end to the profiling it does. That said you can still get a fairly good understanding of the origin of your website's visitors by switching browsers, systems, ISPs and using incognito/private mode. In the current case, the top links are fairly well separated from the subsequent ones.

Comment: Couldn't you simply rollback the edit?

Comment: @AdrienNader, Google actually has ["personalized searches for everybody"](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/personalized-search-for-everyone.html) that are also described in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Personalized_Search).

Comment: @DerGolem: That wouldn't solve the wider issue, would it?

Comment: Well, it would fix a single case.

Comment: @DerGolem: I've already applied rollbacks where appropriate.

Comment: Who cares what the site was "at the time of this post"? I think that's just pedantic. I want to download G++ for 64-bit Windows; I don't want a complete history of all the locations that have ever hosted it. I'd delete the entire "At the time of this post" section and enter the current link -- it's irrelevant what it was "at the time of this post" (though your "current" edited answer is good :) ).

Comment: @DavidS: Which is exactly why questions asking for offsite links are now closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 81):

I just registered on stackoverflow to be able to answer this.

I am the one who has been taking care of the website and domain name for mingw-w64 for a couple years now.

I've been spending quite a lot of time on regaining control for mingw-w64 from sourceforge. Sourceforge has been providing many services which mingw-w64 uses but as you probably know, it has also been behaving in less than perfect ways recently. My concern has been that with the website in the hands of sourceforge, it was very difficult to do anything. More recently I registered mingw-w64.org and with the most recent events, the need to ensure we could easily move away from sourceforge with an actual proper transition plan only got bigger.

Unfortunately, many links point to the sourceforge project page which we have absolutely 0 control on. On the website side we can use a .htaccess file to permanently redirect visitors (that's what is done) but on the project page, we can only push binaries and set a description. Anything we put there is no match for the giant green "DOWNLOAD" buttons that sourceforge puts in ads.
The sourceforge project page is the first result for "mingw-w64" on google.

We really want to ensure things work fine for everyone. We don't want pages to disappear, links to suddenly get broken and everyone to get confused.

Yesterday I started looking for backlinks to the sourceforge project page. There are a lot of them. A LOT. So what should be done? While there is no plan to move off sourceforge at the time, if (or rather when) this happens, the sourceforge project page is the first thing that will cause troubles. If we stop touching it, it is possible that sourceforge puts whatever they feel like on it, with whatever amount of crapware in false mingw-w64 installers.

The current situation is that if these links do not get updated to point to http://mingw-w64.org which is the current website of mingw-w64, they will end up pointing to very outdated files and/or malware'd installers or, better, a non-existing page.

I mailed a few people and I'm actually limited by the tool I use for backlinks (ahrefs.com; I'd need to pay 80 USD/month to get more results at once). I also noticed there were several links on stackoverflow and after mentioning it on IRC, the user you got the request from offered to do these edit requests.

I'd say it's up to every author to accept or not an edit, no matter what it is. What bothered me with you was that I was on IRC on yesterday (I always am) and at some point I saw:

```
21:46 $YOU > [~oftc-webi@XXX.comcast.net] joins #mingw-w64
21:46 $YOU : Can I confirm that http://mingw-w64.org should replace sourceforge as the download link for Win64 mingw tools?
21:50 $YOU : Nevermind, sourceforge clearly has newer everything.  Rejecting the edit suggestion.
21:50 $YOU < [~oftc-webi@XXX.comcast.net] quits []
```

I saw your messages 2 minutes after you left. Or rather, 6 minutes after you joined.

You asked a question and didn't wait for an answer for more than 4 minutes. On sunday evening.

While doing so you've also reached a wrong conclusion.

First there is no "newer everything". If you take a mathematical definition of newer then you could say the sources of mingw-w64 on sourceforge.net are not strictly newer than the ones linked from mingw-w64.org.

Then you're still advocating linking directly to a file dump. It's quite obvious the files will be uploaded to the file dump before the links to these files are added to any website.

It actually looks like you based this on two files. Considering I recently had the displeasure of making a file backup of the file dump and it took me days to get their 81GB, 2 files for a total of 100MB doesn't sounds like a lot.

Lastly, mingw-w64.org is a wiki with open registration and if you believe that some content needs to be fixed, you are more than welcome to improve the website. A website is also a place to teach people and to help them rather than simply providing them with a .exe.

It's getting late for me and I'm sorry if anything sounds angry above but the task is huge and it is painful to have added roadblocks in surprise places (I only found out about this after I checked for updates to the backlinks list on ahrefs.com).

edit: I need to stress out the fact that the sourceforge project page is the past for mingw-w64; currently it's compatibility and later on it'll be deprecation and then removal (if possible); either it's update (when it makes sense obviously but it should if it's about directing users) or dead/broken link.

edit2: I also definitely do not think edits should be a search-and-replace and my SO skill is low enough that I can't list all proposed edits but I also see no issue in either rejecting the edit and updating, or accepting the edit and improving/re-fixing it right after.

Comment: You are welcome to provide edits that incorporate the new URL in a meaningful way.  For example, change the old URLs from links to quoted text (not clickable), and add a footnote with the new download link.  In this fashion, the accurate description of what steps were actually taken while writing a question or answer are preserved, and visitors also see the new link.  The major problem was that the "helpful" user didn't pay any attention to the context of the links, and if someone says "I downloaded it from SourceForge", changing that to "from mingw-w64.org" simply is not true.

Comment: In other words, doing a search-and-replace is not welcome.  Perhaps the user sounded like he was volunteering to put in the effort to do it right, and I understand why you encouraged that, but he didn't, and ended up submitting broken edits.

Comment: As far as "I observed SourceForge to be newer", it's true, and not "based on two files".  SourceForge has the mingw-w64 versions of gcc 5.x.  The [download page on the site being pushed](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download) indicates that the latest version to be found that way is 4.9.

Comment: _"I'd say it's up to every author to accept or not an edit, no matter what it is."_ I see you have the informed badge- Glad you took the tour! But did you also check out the [help]? Because editing is covered in there. Edits are reviewed _for a reason._ (Mostly to stop spam, which this can come across as.) Because they are reviewed, they can be rejected _if they are incorrect for whatever reason._ If reviewers felt that this was incorrect, then they had every right to reject it. In the first case, as well, Ben _was_ the author and had even more right to reject the edit.

Comment: Finally, I really do appreciate you coming here and sharing your side of the story.  We don't want to have outdated URLs.  But blind edits ignoring context are no solution either.  Let's slow down and take the time to craft complete sentences that preserve the story and point anyone looking for current downloads in the right direction as well.

Comment: (Maybe that wasn't finally).  I also apologize for not staying on the IRC channel longer, but I saw literally hundreds of users in the room, and I felt if there really was a known issue with sourceforge not being the right download link, I wouldn't need a direct response from the webmaster, any experienced user would know the right page to link to.  I don't think that all hundreds of users were afk, so I got the impression that it wasn't a cut-and-dried universally-accepted change to the URL.

Comment: Ping me again (using @username notation) when your download page has the right versions in the matrix, and I'll help with edits that differentiate between (where it used to be found) and (where devs should look today).

Comment: You might also do well to make an official statement about moving the official webpage off of SF, as [Steve Jessop suggested in his answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297498/103167)

Comment: And it would be really cool if you had a page or #anchor on the downloads page specifically for the Windows install -- most of the questions and answers here were specifically talking about Windows tools, and when replacing a link to the SF page having "Download - Official Mingw-w64 installer" prominently placed, it would be nice to have one that doesn't require the user to first click "Downloads" and then decide between multiple windows-hosted versions, plus some Mac and Linux packages.

Comment: The reason the page does not always have the most up-to-date links is that it's a separate system from the wiki. I don't touch the sourceforge side anymore but it looks like it insists on featuring the most recent upload and in our case it is often a daily build from dongsheng and that's another reason I want to hide the sourceforge project page behind a page we have full control on. I ask publicly for the pages to be updated (and I hope updating two digits in the wiki is simpler than building a toolchain) but there's some kind of chickend-and-egg problem there.

Comment: I've looked into not having the "files" section with sourceforge projects and even created a new project without this enabled but it was there anyway. I would have liked to remove the links from the sourceforge project page to the file stash and keep the file browsing feature for people who really want to look at what is there but it seems it isn't possible either. I'll try to come up with a solution that guarantees (either programmatically or through some social/human means) that the wiki is updated by whoever uploads something to the sourceforge "file release system".

Comment: If you want a direct link about these, you can use http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds . The page is still barebone and I'm really fighting that: it's not the first time files are uploaded and nothing else is done to advertise them. I also have the feeling that the **current** page is simple enough  with enough clear differentiation between entries that uvisitors do not get stuck wondering where to click next. Any edit to improve it further is welcome too. (since I think that was my last comment I'll ping you: @ben-voigt ; I'll do it again once the up-to-date guarantee is done)

Comment: Text += "... but since [time] has moved to [URL] because of [URL]. The old link shouldn't be used anymore. "; And invalidate the old link with `\``s

Comment: @Nick: Exactly.  Make the old link unclickable, and add the new one as a footnote or such.

Answer (score 30):

To my mind, "immediately useful" trumps "historically accurate".  Especially if the answer is in some sense canonical (accepted, and/or has a substantial number of upvotes), its usefulness down the road to new visitors is more important to the people who actually read it than complete historical accuracy.

Having said that, a careless edit which introduces a falsehood isn't a good thing, either.  My recommendation would be to edit the answer to explain how the original answer was correct at the time, but a better current answer is available.  Often, this would properly belong in a comment; but if the original link is dead or just a "you should not have clicked here", an edit to replace it with a correct, working link is, on balance, a Good Thing.

Obviously, an edit which invalidates the original answer is unacceptable for other reasons, and like you state, this type of question should often be closed as off-topic.

Comment: What do you think about the other linked cases, such as a question listing out the steps performed to reach the problematic result?

Comment: My focus was really on the "why do reviewers accept this?" aspect of your question.  Based on a cursory examination of your examples, those particular edits should probably have been rejected or improved, rather than accepted.

Comment: The question with a link to MinGW doesn't really need the link to be understandable at all; but if complete accuracy is desired, maybe it could be refactored to have both the historical link and a current link. The answer with a link to "these sites" could perhaps similarly be edited to have useful links for future visitors rather than, or at least in preference to, historically accurate links.

Comment: The political aspect of "please don't link to Sourceforge any more" complicates matters here.  Fundamentally, I agree that Sourceforge have squandered their trust, and replacing SourceForge links with current authoritative links elsewhere makes sense as a service to visitors of this site. But again, as ever, there are many cases where blind search and replace is not appropriate.  Either way, if the links were simply broken, they would be pretty harmless; but we don't want visitors to end up installing unwanted software on their systems, do we?

Answer (score 17):

SourceForge is now a malware distribution site;  not the friendly home of open source that it used to be before it was sold in 2012.

If I try to follow the pre-edit URL then I get a message from my malware-blocker (uBlock Origin) that it's blocked access to the page.

I'm in favour of editing out any link to SourceForge if there is an alternative, although in this case perhaps it should also change to say "As of 2015", not "At the time of writing". Anyone who wants to see the old version can check the edit history.

Comment: Well after going through several outdated download catalogs, the suggested corrected site will send visitors to sourceforge in the end anyway, so I guess you're out of luck either way

Comment: @BenVoigt fair point

Comment: Perhaps the title of this meta should be "Editing links to SourceForge" since that seems the real issue

Comment: No, that's really a second, separate issue.  Feel free to open a meta question if you think SF links need to be stamped out.  I started this discussion because ever since "too minor" was eliminated as a rejection reason, it's been acceptable for edits to leave the post in need of further editing.  I wanted to see whether anyone would argue that these edits are improvements, moving in the right direction, and should be accepted even though they are incomplete, on the basis of "minor/incomplete edits are ok".  Consensus seems to agree with me, though.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I think you should submit a meta question, if not already present, to mass-change any sourceforge link to possible new ones. I think SF should be removed from questions because the site itself distributes malware through installers. And beyond that, most projects are now hosted on the author's own server or Github.It will take some research and time, but this is definitely something to be done. We do not need to point people new to programming to download software that hides malware.

Comment: @onebree OK. I guess there is also the issue of widely-used projects like mingw-w64 that don't appear to have any other hosting.

Comment: @MattMcNabb in those cases, we can at least point the user to the main site, which ends up leading to where it is hosted. It is better than giving direct traffic to SF.

Comment: Can we please use the right terms for crapware/bundleware?  Diluting "malware" to include things that are harmless-but-annoying does no one any favors; users rapidly forget just how harmful the real threats (like rootkits and worms) can be.

Comment: @BenVoigt To pick one example... [BinkiLand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_hijacking#Binkiland) installs itself as a windows service, hijacks the browser and phones home. This is well within malware territory for me. Who knows what the service might be doing? It is a gross privacy violation.

Answer (score 10):

In short, edits to update links should pay attention to the context in which the link appears.

The root of the problem I think is that your answer contains parenthetical information that *looks* at a lazy brief glance as though it answers the question, but in fact isn't the answer. So in some sense it doesn't matter whether the link is to the current distribution of the software, or the domain has lapsed and now contains porn. It doesn't *claim* to be a link to mingw-w64, so as far as it goes there's no strict need to update it even if the location of the software has changed. There's nothing inherently wrong with having explanatory non-answer information in answers, but supposing the link were now definitely wrong (and for example led to malware, which some would argue is now a real risk on sourceforge), then it would be strange to insist on retaining such dangerous stuff for the sake of the historical integrity of the answer.

The question "Where could I have got a GCC/G++ compiler for my 64-bit Windows 7 machine on November 7th 2010?", quite aside from being a resource request, is "too localised". The question is about mingw-w64, it is not about 2010 search results. So we don't want to keep the link and the anecdote about what happened in 2010 because it's in any way "correct" to have it, we want to keep it as an example of what the result might be of the search you propose.

So the proposed edit *could* have been to add, if it were true, "this is no longer the correct location as of [whenever], for [whyever], the correct location is now [wherever]", which actually would have strengthened your point that these things are subject to change. It might have weakened your point that the top search result is the right answer to the question, though, since presumably when a project leaves sourceforge there will be some time during which sourceforge remains the top result despite no longer being blessed by the project maintainers.

Alternatively, the proposed edit *could have been*, if it were true, to replace the 2010 example with "as of 22nd June 2015, the top result was [whatever]". I think keeping this up to date would miss the point of suggesting the search as answer to the question, but would at least be a true statement. In fact it is still sourceforge, so that edit is not warranted (or not yet).

However badly sourceforge has behaved, personally I think it's for individual projects to leave it if they choose, and nominate a new primary download location. Roaming around the place erasing links to sourceforge should only come after the particular project has explicitly deprecated sourceforge as a source for their code. Then where someone does link to a download location in a way that ought to be kept current, the edit comments could say for example ("Updated Notepad++ link: see https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-plus-plus-leaves-sf.html for notice of the move"). Others would then not be in the position of needing to research the issue independently from scratch in order to confirm the edit.

This editor has tried to do that: "this was requested in #mingw-w64 at oftc.net". Unfortunately the reference was not sufficiently precise or authoritative for you to be able to confirm that the new location is better, let alone to justify rewriting your anecdote.

Comment: Yes, I would have looked at the edit much more favorably if it had changed the entire sentence to make a true statement involving the new URL.  And, of course, if it wasn't introducing a link to an unmaintained page with old version information.

Answer (score 9):

I'm willing to bet that this is the result of someone wanting to update the links of MinGW to point to a site that isn't Sourceforge.

Personally, I don't think that the link should be updated since it invalidates the answer; the new site didn't exist back when the question as answered, so what's being said is plain wrong.

However, I also can respect the desire to change the URLs around so they point to the [theoretically] right place.

I think that edits like this should be rejected.  If they want to offer a revision on the link, then a comment is a better place to do it.  Or better yet, the [mingw-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw-w64) tag wiki would be the best place to do it (and it may already have it there).

Comment: You think because of the flak SF has taken for bundling crapware in installer downloads?

Comment: *Easily*.  But I'm looking more objective than that; if someone wants to change the links to their product, the tag wiki is the best spot to do that.

Comment: I think you are correct, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2478571/poqdavid?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1).

Comment: This is going to be a repeat of what I wrote elsewhere except much shorter (plus now I can comment on SO :) ). The recent issues with sourceforge did indeed play a large role in this. Basically the new website and domain were already worked on but the recent events have increased the need to update the remaining links in order to not be dependent upon SF.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are saying in this answer. Does this answer favor keeping broken/undesirable links in favor of post history?

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to propose the following rules (or hints):

When a link points to a deprecated/removed page (here, the sourceforge project page), replace it with a link to the new page and add a note about the edit at the end of the post. The note only needs to mention the prior URI but shouldn't be a link since the goal is to deprecate it.

If there is no replacement (for instance the link was a direct link to a .exe from 2009), keep it but strike it and add a note at the end of post explaining where to look now.

Since links are all grouped at the end of messages, it didn't seem very practical to add the explanation right after the link that has been changed. I hope this approach will ensure the links are immediately useful to readers without changing the meaning of answers in ways that voters didn't expect.

I've just done an edit which can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8542770 (I'm not sure the link will remain valid once the edit has been accepted or rejected). Please tell whether you agree with the way it has been done.

tl:dr; yes, do such edits, but leave a clear explanation and do it on a case-by-case basis; remaining true to the original meaning is most important; this is not about rewriting history but helping users (this is probably obvious but a reminder never hurts)

Comment: That edit is fine but uninteresting; it is one of the cases when the URL could have simply been replaced by itself, since it is a product link and not part of a historical account.

Answer (score -7):

Well if people want to see what url was they simply can check the edits done to the post and i was just trying to fix the links and helping to keep the links correct and also most of edits i done got accepted i don't know why you rejected the rest of my edits it's not right that was simple url fix and why don't you let the one who made the post to decide

Comment: Why would someone think to change the history, when the result of your edit is a strong claim "I downloaded the tools from http://mingw-w64.org".  The claim isn't incomplete which might cause people to do more research, it is WRONG.  Fixing URLs is not a simple edit, and **you cannot blindly change just the URL without considering the rest of the post**.

Comment: The reason most of your edits got accepted was that the reviewers were not paying attention, blindly trusting the edit.  I had to rollback many of them.  For example, you cannot change a sourced quote from the SourceForge page to cite the new page instead.  (Even worse, the quoted text does not exist on the new page at all, but all cases of citation revisionism are dishonest).  And I'm not a rogue actor, every experienced user who has expressed an opinion has agreed with me, and even Adrien who asked you to do the edits agreed that they aren't as simple as replacing the URL.

Comment: Then, you didn't take a hint when some edits got rejected to slow down and ask what was wrong with them, you kept making more bad edits and even resubmitting the rejected ones.  (Not that it would have helped, even with all the information on this page you still claim to have no clue what was wrong with the edits)

Comment: @BenVoigt Hmm ok but i don't remember resubmitting a rejected edit and so whats going to happen once the project on sourceforge.net is gone and also tell me how i can fix my edits

Comment: How to fix your edits: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5861891/revisions and compare your wrong edit (said the user downloaded something from a site they never used) to my edit (removes the old link and adds the new one, without changing what the user says they did).  You'll have to look at each question and answer separately and THINK about how the link is related to the context.

Comment: [Here is your edit being rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8525582) and [here is where you submitted the exact same edit again less than an hour later](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8525816)

Comment: @BenVoigt Well i didn't noticed and i just meant to help, oh i get it now so we don't remove the old data we keep and add extra info

Comment: @BenVoigt i wonder if you fixed all my edits if not i am going to look at them and see if i done anything wrong and fix it

Comment: No, I haven't fixed all of them, so you can try again. I suggest a few at a time and then get feedback again.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well thanks for giving me the chance to fix them but it looks like i am temp banned sorry.

Comment: Yeah well... I requested that, and it seems a moderator agreed.  Please understand that the purpose of a short suspension of editing privilege is to let you know something's wrong so that you come read the discussion and learn how to do better.  I have no way to know when you will be allowed to edit again, I think either 1 or 3 days is normal.  What's actually worse than the bad edit suggestions are the reviewers who voted to approve them -- they work against the whole purpose of edit reviews, which is to make sure that new users get the advice needed to make contributions that are

Comment: not just borderline, but great.  By coming and joining the discussion, you've shown your willingness to do that, which is best for everyone.

Comment: Putting a full. Stop between every. Few words will. Do wonders to. Improve your credibility.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks :) as soon as i get unbanned i will recheck my edits this time i will think more about them :)

Comment: @BenVoigt i edited 2 of my posts to correct my error can you tell me how are there here is the links [Edit 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930826/how-to-enable-experimental-c11-concurrency-features-in-mingw/26441951#26441951) and [Edit 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004419/opencv-2-3-doesnt-compile-undefined-reference-error/22969631#22969631)

Comment: @LukePeterson can you tell me why you rejected the edit what part of it was wrong?